# What about tuple error in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to learn a little machine learning (and python), for now classifying with k-Nearest Neighbors. I get this error (what's going on?):

```
dataSetSize = dataSet.shape[0]
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

**Checking for callable:**

```
>>> callable(group)
False
>>> callable(labels)
False
>>> g = group()
```

They are false, but how to make them True?

**The data:**

```
>>> group
array([[ 1. ,  1.1],
       [ 1. ,  1. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0.1]])
>>> labels
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']
```

When I do this on my group variable I get this:

```
group.shape[0]
4
```

My call to this function:

```
>>> kNN.classify0([0, 0], group, labels, 3)



def classify0(inX, dataSet, labels, k):
     dataSetSize = dataSet.shape[0]
     diffMat = tile(inX, (dataSetSize,1)) - dataSet
     sqDiffMat = diffMat**2
     sqDistances = sqDiffMat.sum(axis=1)
     distances = sqDistances**0.5
     sortedDistIndices = distances.argsort()
     classCount = {}
     for i in range(k):
       voteIlabel = labels[sortedDistIndices[i]]
       classCount[voteIlabel] = classCount.get(voteIlabel, 0) + 1
     sortedClassCount = sorted(classCount.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
     return sortedClassCount[0][0]
```

Comment: more code is needed for a clearer picture

Comment: what is dataset here ? You sure error is coming from that line ?

Comment: Nothing is being called here ... At best, with this code you'd get an `AttributeError`, or a "... can't be indexed because it doesn't have `__getitem__`" type message I think (unless `__getitem__` is calling something further down ...).  Can you post the full traceback at least?

Comment: Please provide more details.. What are you trying to achieve? What's the value of dataSet?

Comment: google + "'tuple' object is not callable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check using the built in `callable` function to check if a object is callable :
`callabe(object)` => returns `True` if object is callable

Answer (score 2):

It means its not callable. You get the same error if you try to call something from an integer. You can call `dataSet[0].shape` most likely. It's hard to know, since i don't know what is located at dataSet[0]

Answer (score -1):

You are not passing the variable correctly.

```
kNN.classify0([2,2], group, labels, 3)
```

Group is not set